# Determine if items can be ordered grouping two simultaneous criteria

Tags: graphs, reference-request, decision-problem

For a set of items with two properties, how can it be detemined if they can be ordered in a way so that for every value of either property all items of that value are grouped together.

Obviously trying every possible ordering is out of the question.

For example, if each item has a number and a letter, the following sequence satisfies the condition:

```
A1->A2->A3->B3->B4->C4->D4
\---A----/  \-B--/  \-C--/
 1   2  \-3--/  \---4----/
```

But the following sets cannot possibly be ordered in this way:

```
A1, A2, A3, B1, C2, D3

A1, A2, B1, B2
```

I came up with a solution which is a little long to describe and seems to work, but I was curious:

Is this a known problem? Can it be reduced to a known problem?

Comment: There are several possible lexicographic orderings. If none fulfills your requirements, can there be another ordering?

Comment: What do you mean? If it is not possible to order them in a way that fulfills the requirement the algorithm should return false.

Comment: I mean, is it sufficient to check all lexicographic orderings?

Comment: Do you mean lex, colex and their reverses?

Comment: I don't know these terms. Lexicographic order is standard, I think, but in your case you could impose different orders on the components, and chose which components to compare first. So you can have $2 \cdot |X|! \cdot |Y|!$ many lexicographic orderings, with $X$ the set of letters and $Y$ the set of numbers (if both are finite).

Comment: @Raphael, I don't think lexicographic ordering is relevant here: I think *any* ordering is allowed, as long as the letters are properly grouped and the numbers are properly grouped.

Answer (score 3):

There is a $O(n)$ time algorithm for your problem, using standard graph algorithms.  You basically reduce it to connected components decomposition, which can be done in linear time.

Build an undirected (multi-)graph, where we have one vertex for each letter in the input.  For each pair of items that share the same number, say Xi and Yi, add an undirected edge between X and Y.  This might introduce repeated edges.  That's ok.  Leave them as is; don't collapse them down to a single edge.

Once you have this graph, your items can be ordered if and only if every connected component of this graph is a simple path.  You can test this condition by decomposing into connected components using standard algorithms, then for each connected component, checking that no vertex has degree $\ge 3$ and that either (i) the component consists of only a single vertex, or (b) there exist exactly two vertices in the component with degree 1.  The whole thing can be done in linear time.

---

The idea here is that we're trying to find an ordering of the letters (the vertices), subject to some constraints: each edge (X,Y) represents a constraint that the letter X has to be adjacent to Y in the final ordering of letters.  The graph I defined above encodes exactly the constraints that apply, if we want to find an ordering of the items.  Notice that there exists a valid ordering of the items if and only if there exists a valid ordering of the letters that respects the edge-constraints: given an ordering of the letters, each letter represents the group of items containing that letter, and you can easily arrange what order to put the numbers in.

The key insight here is to build a graph with one vertex per *letter* rather than one vertex per item.  Once you do that, everything falls out more or less straightforwardly.

Credits: I thank Raphael for a crucial idea that helped me find this,  AlexDev for pointing out some subtleties that helped me work out the details, and reinierpost, whose answer helped me realize a few other tricky details.

By the way, you might notice that my solution ends up looking very similar to [reinierpost's elegant algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/44466/755).  Indeed, when the graph is connected, my solution is equivalent to his algorithm: his y[A] is just the degree of the vertex A in the graph I defined.  The difference comes when the graph is not connected; my algorithm handles that case correctly, but I think his algorithm gets a few corner cases wrong.  Nonetheless, the ideas are extremely similar -- and I hope my exposition helps understand the ideas behind his elegant algorithm.

---

This algorithm also generalizes to the case where you have more than two attributes.  For instance, suppose each item has a letter, a number, and a color.  Start by forming a graph with a vertex per letter and an edge (X,Y) whenever there are two items that share an attribute and whose letters are X,Y respectively; use the same techniques to look for a valid ordering of the letters.  Then, for each letter, you need to look for a valid ordering of the items containing that letter.  This can be done by a recursive call.  There is a slight twist, in that during recursive calls you might have an additional constraint indicating which item the sequence must start and/or end at, but it's easy to adjust the algorithm to take this into account.  In this way you get an algorithm whose running time is $O(kn)$, where $n$ is the number of items and $k$ the number of attributes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I don't understand your objection.  The ordering A1, A2, C2, B2, B3 meets all the requirements.  That has both the letters properly "grouped" (all A's are adjacent, all C's are adjacent) and the numbers properly "grouped" (all 2's are adjacent).  In particular, once you know that the ordering A1, A2, B2, B3 is valid, then it's trivial to figure out where to insert the C2 into that ordering: you put it with the 2's, in the middle of the 2's, where it won't disrupt the A's or B's.  There's only one place it can go, and it's trivial to identify it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, maybe it'll help if I mention this: as I read the question, the letters don't have to appear in alphabetical order, and the numbers don't have to appear in increasing order.  For instance, B3, B2, C2, A2, A1 would also be a valid ordering.

Comment: You're right. I must have misunderstood something but I'm not sure what, now. :-)

Comment: The first part (deleting values that appear once and making sure the remaining ones don't appear more than twice) I agree with entirely since it's how my solution started. For the second part you say that for each guess an O(n) scan would detect if the sequence is good. For that to work I would need to build an adjacency list first, right? It could be done in n^2, possibly even n log(n). And I would start only from nodes with one adjacency.

Comment: Actually I would probably build the adjacency list in one of the previous steps, i.e. while counting each letter and number I would already create a structure to traverse them.

Comment: If every component appears exactly twice, model the input as graph (entries become nodes; connect with an edge if they have to be adjacent). An Euler path in this graph corresponds do a valid ordering, doesn't it? (This even works for the original problem, I think.) If so, we get a linear-time algorithm with your reduced instance.

Comment: @Raphael except if there are cycles. In fact my solution was to create a graph after deleting unnecessary nodes and verifying there are no cycles. I don't have proof, but I believe that if there are no cycles and no node has more than two adjacencies, a path that satisfies the requirement can always be found.

Comment: @D.W. even with an adjacency list you still have a problem if you have disjoint subgraphs.

Comment: @AlexDev Cyclic graphs can have Euler paths (I think), but not all, of course. I recommend you check out the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). (Maybe I'm wrong -- I did not think too deeply about this -- but my guess is that we have a characterisation here.)

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the problem. Even though a cyclic graph has a Euler path it won't satisfy the requirement. For example: A1, A2, B1, B2, has a Euler path but can't be ordered because of the cycle. Whichever one you start with will always have to be followed by two nodes, which is impossible.

Comment: @Raphael, thank you for the great insights!  I replaced my answer with a new algorithm, based partly on your ideas.  I think linear time is now achievable.  The Euler path observation was key -- thank you.

Comment: @AlexDev, I've updated my answer.  I think it now handles the kinds of cases you mention exactly correctly.  It turned out that the solution was not to ask "does the graph contain a Euler path?" but rather to ask "is each component itself a simple path and nothing more?".

Comment: @D.W. That's an amazing insight! You only need the constraints of one of the properties to build the graph. But I still think that that first step of eliminating nodes in which one of the properties appears only once is necessary. If you have A1, B1, C1 you don' really have any constraints even though they all share a common number.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @D.W.: I deleted my answer, this improved version is also an improvement on my answer and fixes some errors in it as you say.